# Kymco People 50 vacuum hose (s) diagram

Tags: repair, scooter, vacuum-hoses

Used scooter has all of the hoses disconnected.  One Inlet on the carb, one on the intake manifold. A small junction canister with 6 inlets is under the oil tank. Can't seem to find a diagram anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't have it, I don't know what will:

http://www.49ccscoot.com/manuals/Kymco_People_S_50-200_Service_Manual.pdf